# How to build a string from javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm using javascript, and I have a function which generate for me an array like this :

```
[
 "perfumers/any(perfumer: perfumer/name eq 'Test1')",
 "perfumers/any(perfumer: perfumer/name eq 'Test2')",
 "line_unit/name eq 'EDC'",
 "line_unit/name eq 'EDT'",
 "line_unit/name eq 'EDM'",
 "line_unit/name eq 'EDK'",
 "color/name eq 'RED'",
 "color/name eq 'BLUE'",
]
```

and I want from this array to have string like this :

```
"(perfumers/any(perfumer: perfumer/name eq 'Test1') or perfumers/any(perfumer: perfumer/name eq 'Test2') )

and (line_unit/name eq 'EDC' or line_unit/name eq 'EDT' or line_unit/name eq 'EDM' or line_unit/name eq 'EDK)

and (color/name eq 'RED' or color/name eq 'BLUE')"
```

Do you have any idea please how can do that using javascript ?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. You should show us your conditions to have `or` and `and` in the result.

Comment: Iterate over the array and construct a string with concat and add  the additional characters where needed..

Comment: can you help please I'm not a javascripot expert

Comment: I think it'd separate it into your `or` groups first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const data = [
 "perfumers/any(perfumer: perfumer/name eq 'Test1')",
 "perfumers/any(perfumer: perfumer/name eq 'Test2')",
 "line_unit/name eq 'EDC'",
 "line_unit/name eq 'EDT'",
 "line_unit/name eq 'EDM'",
 "line_unit/name eq 'EDK'",
 "color/name eq 'RED'",
 "color/name eq 'BLUE'",
]

const transform = data => Object.values(data.reduce((res, item) => {
  const [prefix, ...rest] = item.split(' ')
  const existing = res[prefix] || []
  return {
    ...res,
    [prefix]: [...existing, item]
  }
}, {})).map(items => `( ${items.join(' or ')} )`).join(' and ')

console.log(transform(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```js
  const arr=[
    "perfumers/any(perfumer: perfumer/name eq 'Test1')",
    "perfumers/any(perfumer: perfumer/name eq 'Test2')",
    "line_unit/name eq 'EDC'",
    "line_unit/name eq 'EDT'",
    "line_unit/name eq 'EDM'",
    "line_unit/name eq 'EDK'",
    "color/name eq 'RED'",
    "color/name eq 'BLUE'",
  ];

  const text=`(${[arr.filter(i=>i.startsWith('perfumers')).join(' or '),arr.filter(i=>i.startsWith('line_unit')).join(' or '),arr.filter(i=>i.startsWith('color')).join(' or ') ].join(') and (')})`;

  console.log(text);
```

Comment: thnaks for your answer